# Getting a 'Type cannot be converted to JSONObject' error in my Android app when accessing a Render deployed ML model

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, backend, render

```
org.json.JSONException: Value Hello of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I have created an android application in android studio and linked it to a ML model which I have deployed on render. When I am hitting request through postman I am getting the output, but when I am hitting request using app no output is coming.
Can anyone help with it?

```
public class Prediction extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button button5, button6;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    private TextView output;
    TextView user_details;
    EditText age,gender,study_time,smoke,family_income,room_type;
    String url = "https://major-project-1jj5.onrender.com";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prediction);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
        age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
        gender = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.gender);
        study_time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.study_time);
        smoke = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.smoke);
        family_income = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.family_income);
        room_type = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.room_type);

        button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        user_details = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_details);
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();


        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response);
                            String data = jsonObject.getString("hostel_name");
                            if(data.equals("1")){
                                output.setText("Boys Hostel - Room 1");
                            }
                            else if (data.equals("2")){
                                output.setText("Boys Hostel - Room 2");
                            }
                            else if (data.equals("3")){
                                output.setText("Boys Hostel - Room 3");
                            }
                            else if (data.equals("4")){
                                output.setText("Boys Hostel - Room 4");
                            }
                            else if (data.equals("5")){
                                output.setText("Girls Hostel - Room 1");
                            }
                            else if (data.equals("6")){
                                output.setText("Girls Hostel - Room 2");
                            }
                            else if (data.equals("7")){
                                output.setText("Girls Hostel - Room 3");
                            }
                            else if (data.equals("8")){
                                output.setText("Girls Hostel - Room 4");
                            }
                            else {
                                output.setText("Enter Correct Value");
                            }

                        }catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(Prediction.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        } ){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        params.put("age",age.getText().toString());
                        params.put("gender",gender.getText().toString());
                        params.put("study_time",study_time.getText().toString());
                        params.put("smoke",smoke.getText().toString());
                        params.put("room_type",room_type.getText().toString());
                        params.put("family_income",family_income.getText().toString());
                        return params;
                    }

                };
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Prediction.this);
                queue.add(stringRequest);

            }
        });

        if (user == null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else {
            user_details.setText(user.getEmail());
        }
        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

First I used POST method and error occured. Then I used GET method error was solved code is running but output is not there. I have checked the url on postman its working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z025G.png)